# Android saving data within the phone

Tags: android, android-xml

In my android application I have to store some application settings and some user information within the phone.

I can go for the  shared preference option explained in this [DOCUMENTATION](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

But wondering if I can store data as objects wise within the phone. I found this [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816695/android-sharedpreferences-with-serializable-object) regarding saving serialized objects in files and bit not sure of any issues if I go with this way to store persistent data.

Also would like to know what the best way to deal with insert/delete/update and read with XML files in android. Would appreciate any guidance. Thanks in advance...!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is only a small amount of data you need to store, then go with the built-in shared preferences, that is what the functionality is there for. SQLite and OrmLite are a bit heavyweight in this situation IMO. Even if you want to handle the data as Objects; in which case I would serialise to / deserialise from JSON or XML stored in text files and handle the insert/update/delete on the deserialised objects in your model.

Comment: HI paulkayuk, what method do you think is the best to write, delete and update data with xml files in the android internal storage. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to persist some objects I think you should use [`SQLiteDatabase`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html), it would be a more cleaner solution than using serialization in files. You will indeed need to write some extra code for your `Database` but you will end up with a cleaner implementation in my opinion. You could also be using [`OrmLite for Android`](http://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml) which is pretty robust and easy to use if you have some basic `orm` knowledge.

Comment: Hi Ovidiu Latcu, Thanks. In my scenario I just dont have that much data. just few objects. Do you think still its worth while for go for a database solution? Also they are don't have a clear relationship to devide in to tables with foreign keys and all. Do you think its better to go for a XML solution?