# What does Context mean in Android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is Context in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-in-android)

I would like to have an answer on this question [Android - SharedPreferences with serializable object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816695/android-sharedpreferences-with-serializable-object):

```
LocalPersistence LP=new LocalPersistence();
Asortiment=(Nomenklatura) LP.readObjectFromFile(???, filename);
```

But can't understand what to pass instead of `Context context` in main activity?

Comment: I try to pas it, but I get message: Application has stopped unexpectedly for: FileInputStream fileIn = context.getApplicationContext().openFileInput(filename); Maybe filename is wrong

Comment: Post a stack trace, or at least the Exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in the `Activity`, you can pass `this`. Otherwise (for example if you are inside another class), you can always use `MyActivity.this` to get a app-wide available reference to the activity object (there is always only one).