# How to convert String back to Array from Preference

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, android-preferences

`InetAddress.getAllByName(host);` returns me array in below format

```
www.google.com/74.233.233.22
www.google.com/74.233.233.21
www.google.com/74.233.233.23
```

I am converting above result into String and storing in Android Shared Preference

```
String all = inetAddress[i].toString();
```

Now when I retrieve back from preference it will return me `String` which is obvious, but I want it in array format like `inetAddress[i]`.

```
www.google.com/74.233.233.22 
www.google.com/74.233.233.21
www.google.com/74.233.233.23
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an InetAddress from a String using `InetAddress.getByName("yourstring")`

Loop through your Strings and convert them to InetAddresses -

```
String[] addresses = getStringArrayOfAddresses();
InetAddress[] inets = new InetAddress[addresses.length];
for ( int i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++ ) {
    inets[i] = InetAddress.getByName(addresses[i]);
}
```

If your String is one long String, you can split this string using the `split()` String method.

```
String addresses = "www.google.com/74.233.233.22 www.google.com/74.233.233.21";
String[] addrSplit = addresses.split(" ");
System.out.println(addrSplit[0]); // will give www.google.com/74.233.233.22
```

Comment: Tom, Thanks for help. But this I am anyway doing and hence because of that i am getting below results and setting it in Preference by converting into String

www.google.com/74.233.233.22

www.google.com/74.233.233.21

www.google.com/74.233.233.23

But the real challenge comes when i need to retrive data back from Preference, i get in string, I want that in Array in same below format 

www.google.com/74.233.233.22

www.google.com/74.233.233.21

www.google.com/74.233.233.23

For that any solution ?

Comment: Could you please describe what you are currently getting instead?

Comment: Yes this will return the result in same format. But now when I compare dataset between both result, it will show me failed. I am not sure what could be reason, may be one is String array and another is InetAddress array. If i compare inetAddress[] with inetAddress[] dataset it will compare but not with what we just converted now in String[] addrSplit

1) InetAddress[] inetAddress
and 
2) String[] addrSplit

Comment: Is there any way to convert "InetAddress[] inetAddress" into similar String[] addrSplit format ? I mean into "String Array Format" ?

Answer (score 0):

I only suggest this because you are saving the result of a network operation. Obviously that is slow and you don't want to keep repeating it.

A Java array is an object that implements Serializable. It's extremely simple to write an array to a file and then unmarshall it from a file at a later point. Your Preference would then be a string that contains the name of the file where the data is serialized.

Check the answer here for the code:

[Android - SharedPreferences with serializable object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816695/android-sharedpreferences-with-serializable-object)

Comment: InetAddress is also Serializable. This method requires extra work when non-serializable objects are involved (use a wrapper class to solve that).