# losing Activity details after startActivity() method in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have 2 major activity in my project Connect+Details and Menu. After I switch between the first activity to the second everything goes well. the problem start in returning back from 'Menu' to 'Connect+Details'.

when I use the back key to switch between the second activity and go back to the first everything goes well.

problem start when I use this code:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, ConnectActivity.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

I do go back to 'Connect+Details' but every detail in that activity is lost.

my question is simple, how can i go back to previews activity and still have the details used in that activity.

Edit:
the same thing goes even when I am in the 4th, 5th activity so `finish()` didn't help me.

Comment: in manifest file, in your  Connect activity set saved instance is true.

Comment: Why do you use an `Intent` to go back to the Connect `Activity`? If you have already created it then you shouldn't need to do this

Comment: I do not know any other way to go back to used activity

Comment: Oh, I see, sorry wasn't thinking. It depends on what is in your `Activivty` that you want to save

Comment: I need to save up to 6 serializable objects.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to either save your data in `SharedPreferences` or in a database then use the saved data to repopulate your `Activity`. You can use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) to save a `key/value` pair when you leave your `Connect Activity` and this will persist even if your app is closed.

If there will be a lot of data stored then you may consider using an [SQLite DB](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db). This can be a little trickier to set up and use but may be worth it if you are storing a lot of data...especially if its for different users.

Both of these options will persist your data when you leave the `Activity` or the program. You could also use a `static Array` but one of the first two options will probably be better for you.

The **[Storage Options Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)** has some decent examples to get you started, especially if you decide that Shared Preferences will work for you.

**Edit**

Unless something has changed, you can't store serializable objects in `SharedPreferences`. But [Here is a SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816695/android-sharedpreferences-with-serializable-object) that discusses saving them to a file and reading from there. Maybe this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Intent to move from 'Menu' to 'Connect+Details' instead call finish(); from it

Only use intent in first class to move to second ie;'Connect+Details' to 'Menu'

Don't call finish() in Connect+Details

Comment: OK thank you, but what do I do if I want to go from an activity that comes after "menu"?

Comment: I dont get u,u need to move from Connect+Details->Menu and Menu<-Connect+Details, now do u need to move from Menu -> otherclass? is it

Comment: connect+details -> menu -> add new client -> update client -> connect+details. that is my loop the major thing is that in 'connect+details there is properties of my connection to the server. that connection must not be altered and can not be renew as long as the app is running