# Android - Save preferences per object

Tags: android, preferences

Is there any way to save preferences per complex objects?
I have a dynamic list of objects that each contains 3 strings and 2 dynamic lists of pair of booleans. Is there any way to save those objects like preferences?

Comment: What have you considered? Refer to Android documentation on storage options.

Comment: I did something similar by doing everything to JSON to string and then storing in prefs.

Comment: I just ask if it possible to save preferences per objects in android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the option to serialize your complex objects to a file. Then deserialize to recreate the object back from the file. This is not much different from saving to SharedPreferences.

You can refer the code here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5816861/2107118

*Note*: Do make your complex object implement Serializable interface and provide a  serialVersionUID.

Comment: I don't know how much objects do I have (the user decide)

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. You just need to give a unique name to the file. It is almost similar to SharedPreferences.edit().put methods which take a key. In this case the key is the file name.

Comment: Is there any way to use SharedPreferences instead Serialize?

Comment: SharedPreferences doesn't support complex objects. You may try to convert the object to JSON or XML and then put it as a string in the preferences. But that is what serialization is doing for you.

Comment: But how the SharedPreferences will know that the same name of property belongs to different objects?

Comment: Right .. think of SharedPreferences as a HashMap. You need to have separate names for different objects. You cannot use the same name of the property for different objects. The name is kind of pointer to a particular object and you cannot point to different objects at the same time with a single name.