# How to make a dynamic SharedPreferences list that works with arrays and ArrayAdapters?

Tags: android, list, arraylist, sharedpreferences, android-arrayadapter

I've found several similar pages that haven't quite been able to address my dilemna. Here goes:

I would like to be able to create a SharedPreferences list in Android that is extractable with an iterator (loop). Somehow I need to be able to add to a list with a key-value of "[Arrayname]+[element_number]" format. I also need to be able to add/remove values at will.

-- How will I be able to add to the end if I don't know how long the current SharedPrefs list is?

-- I also need the length of the SharedPrefs list to create arrays from it.

Answer (score 1):

You get the a map of all values contained into a SharedPreferences instance with the [getAll() method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getAll%28%29). You can then convert it to a list.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest working with a regular in data container (e.g. ArrayList or HashMap).

you can store the container in the shared preference by serializing it: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5816861/1393632

Now you just need to keep it in sync with your shared preference when updating it.