# Put an ArrayList<String> into an ArrayList<Custom Object>

Tags: java, android, arrays, object

I get data from shared preferences:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = ImageListViewActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("settings",Context.MODE_PRIVATE;
String MyString1 = sharedPref.getString("MyPackage.NameOfSharedPref",null);
String MyString2 = sharedPref.getString("MyPackage.NameOfSharedPref",null);
String MyString3 = sharedPref.getString("MyPackage.NameOfSharedPref",null);
```

It looks like:

```
MyString1 = "Ben, David, Tom, Jessica"
MyString2 = "25, 27, 21, 22"
MyString3 = "male, male, male, female"
```

I splitt it into String Arrays:

```
String[] splitt1 = MyString1.split(",");
String[] splitt2 = MyString2.split(",");
String[] splitt3 = MyString3.split(",");
```

Now I put it into an ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList1 = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < MyString1.length; i++) {
  arrayList1 .add(MyString1[i]);
}

ArrayList<String> arrayList2 = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < MyString2.length; i++) {
  arrayList2 .add(MyString2[i]);
}

ArrayList<String> arrayList3 = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < MyString3.length; i++) {
  arrayList3 .add(MyString3[i]);
}
```

How can I put the values of the ArrayList into a custom Object Array?
I have one object class with constructor, getters and setters.

```
public class Student {
  private String Name;
  private String Age;
  private String Sex;

  public Student(String name, String age, String sex) {
    this.Name = name;
    this.Age = age;
    this.Sex = sex;   
  }

  public String getName() {
    return Name;
  }

  public void setName(String artikelnummer) {
    Name = name;
  }

  public String getAge() {
    return Age;
  }

  public void setAge(String artikelnummer) {
    Age = age;
  }

  public String getSex() {
    return sex;
  }

  public void setSex(String artikelnummer) {
    Sex = sex;
  }
```

Now I want to fill my Student Object Array, I tried this way, but this is my String Arrays that I fill and it doesn't work:

```
ArrayList<Students> peopleList = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < splitt1.length; i++) {
   peoplelist.add(splitt1[i]);
}
```

I want to sort my ArrayLists and write them into an ObjectArrayList like this:

```
Student Stu1 = new Student("Ben","25","male");
Student Stu2 = new Student("David","27","male");
Student Stu3 = new Student("Tom","21","male");
Student Stu4 = new Student("Jessica","22","female");
```

Please Help me, thank you in anticipation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
 ArrayList<Student> peopleList = new ArrayList<>();

   for (int i = 0; i < splitt1.length; i++) {
         Student Student = new Student(splitt1[i],splitt2[i],splitt[i]);
        peoplelist.add(Student );
     }
```

change the model class name from **Students** to **Student**

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a `Student` object e.g.

```
for (int i = 0; i < splitt1.length; i++) {
     String name = splitt1[i].trim(); remove whitespaces
     String age = splitt2[i].trim(); remove whitespaces
     String gender = splitt3[i].trim(); remove whitespaces
     peoplelist.add(new Student(name, age, gender));
}
```

This will solve your issue as of now. You have to keep in mind that the length of your `ArrayList` has to be the exactly the same otherwise you will get `IndexOutOfBondException`.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have the same size of the string from:

```
MyString1 = "Ben, David, Tom, Jessica"
MyString2 = "25, 27, 21, 22"
MyString3 = "male, male, male, female"
```

Which you can get from:

```
String[] splitt1 = MyString1.split(",");
String[] splitt2 = MyString2.split(",");
String[] splitt3 = MyString3.split(",");
```

You can use the length of the splitted String as the for loop count.

You need to create the Student list from your `Students` **pojo** (it should be `Student` to describe a single object). From your pojo, you have a constructor:

```
public Student(String name, String age, String sex) {
  ...
}
```

So, you can use it to create the Student object. Therefore, you can use the following code:

```
List<Students> students = new ArrayList<>();
// using splitt1.length - 1 because index is starting from zero for list.
for (int i = 0; i < splitt1.length - 1; i++) {
  // use .trim() for removing extra whitespace.
  Students student = new Student(splitt1[i].trim(), splitt2[i].trim(), splitt3[i].trim());
  students.add(student);
}
```

**Side note:**

Instead using single preference entry for the string, you can use Gson to save the object to the SharedPreference read more at https://stackoverflow.com/a/38089938/4758255

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < splitt1.length; i++) {
        arrayList1 .add(splitt1[i]);
    }

ArrayList<String> arrayList2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < splitt2.length; i++) {
        arrayList2 .add(splitt2[i]);
    }

ArrayList<String> arrayList3 = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < splitt3.length; i++) {
        arrayList3 .add(splitt3[i]);
    }
```